# How to hide part of layout when editText is selected

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Is there a way how to hide some buttons when i click on EditText and keybord shows?

I have this layout

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout">


<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"

    android:id="@+id/table">


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tariffRow">

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Název"
            android:padding="3dip" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tariffName"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip" />
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button android:id="@+id/okBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Ok"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/stornoBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Storno" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now when the editText is clicked to type some value i need to hide that linearLayout android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout" because otherwise it is still visible above the keyboard.

Comment: does my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set a `FocusChangeListener` to the `EditText` which triggers whenever focus changes on that `EditText` as follow:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // hide relative layout
        } else {
            // show relative layout
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not actually working, check my resolution below.

Comment: Actually that works no need to do that your way EspeH

Answer (score 0):

It is not actually that simple, here is my solution how I got it working.

First Need to **create MyEditText.java**

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    private KeyImeChange keyImeChangeListener;

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public void setKeyImeChangeListener(KeyImeChange keyImeChange){
        keyImeChangeListener = keyImeChange;
    }

    public interface KeyImeChange {
        public boolean onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme (int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent){
        if(keyImeChangeListener != null){
            return keyImeChangeListener.onKeyIme(keyCode, keyEvent);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then **layout.xml**, change following

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tariffName"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
```

Into

```
    <!-- change yourapp -->
    <com.yourapp.MyEditText
        android:id="@+id/tariffName"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip" />
```

Add also **android:focusable="true"** to your **LinearLayout**

```
<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:focusable="true">
```

Then put into your activity like **MainActivity.java**,

```
import fi.hgs.apps.MyEditText.KeyImeChange; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    removeFocus();

    MyEditText myEditText = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.tariffName);
    myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus) {
                showLinearLayout();
            } else {
                hideLinearLayout();
            }
        }
    });
    myEditText.setKeyImeChangeListener(new KeyImeChange() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == event.getKeyCode()) {
                removeFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Add also these to do the actual job.

```
public void removeFocus() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.InnerRelativeLayout);
    linearLayout.requestFocus();
}
public void showLinearLayout() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.InnerRelativeLayout);
    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
public void hideLinearLayout() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.InnerRelativeLayout);
    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```